# Relative URL path for linkid.js

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to host the JS files `linkid.js` and `analytics.js` locally in our dedicated CDN server. 
right now we are referencing to both files as follow:

```
(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga')
```

and

```
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
```

is it easy for me to change the URL reference for `analytics.js` but i am not sure if I can do that for linkid.js!
Looked for documentation but couldn't find an answer if it accepts a relative URL or not. How to handle this situation

**EDIT 1:** 
The reason why i need to do that:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Due to security reason, the require command doesn't allow you to source random script tags; Only the official plugins and locally hosted.

You will have to add another tag to your page:

```
<script async src="https://mycnd.com/linkid.js"></script>
```

and then use:

```
ga('require', 'linkid', 'https://mycnd.com/linkid.js');
```

Setting the url in the 3rd param will trip the security settings and prevent it from loading.  The plugin will get loaded once the  tag loads.

Do you really need to host it on your own CDN?  Mind sharing your reasons?